# What is org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent?

Tags: configuration, eclipse-plugin

I'm just going through the step-by-step introduction *Content and Action Binding* of the *Platform Plug-in Developer Guide* of the [neon Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp).

Step 3 requires one to

> Add a `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer` extension that has includes of `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent`

I tried to figure out what *resourceContent* actually is. From my understanding it is..

1. ..not a class.
2. ..not a package.
3. ..not an extension point.
4. ..badly documented.

Maybe it's just an id. But if so, what is it referencing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the id of one particular navigator content extension declared using the `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent` extension point. This particular id is declared in the `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources` plugin.

The full declaration of this content extension is:

```xml
<extension  
     point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
  <navigatorContent
        name="%resource.extension.name"
        priority="low"
        icon="$nl$/icons/full/eview16/resource_persp.gif"
        activeByDefault="true"
        contentProvider="org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.workbench.ResourceExtensionContentProvider"
        labelProvider="org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.workbench.ResourceExtensionLabelProvider"            
        id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent">         
     <enablement>
             <or>         
                <instanceof 
                        value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource" /> 
             </or>
     </enablement>

    <commonSorter
          class="org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.workbench.ResourceExtensionSorter"
          id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.sorters.defaultSorter">
       <parentExpression>
              <or>           
                <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource" /> 
             </or>
       </parentExpression>
    </commonSorter>
    <dropAssistant
          class="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ResourceDropAdapterAssistant"
          id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.resourceDropAdapter">
       <possibleDropTargets>
          <or>
             <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"/>
             <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder"/>
             <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"/>
          </or>
       </possibleDropTargets>
    </dropAssistant>
    <dropAssistant
          class="org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.workingsets.ProjectInWorkingSetDropAdapterAssistant"
          id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.projectInWorkingSetDropAdapter">
       <possibleDropTargets>
         <adapt type="org.eclipse.ui.IWorkingSet"/>
       </possibleDropTargets>
    </dropAssistant>

    <actionProvider
          class="org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.EditActionProvider"
          id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.actions.EditActions"/>         
    <actionProvider
          class="org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.RefactorActionProvider"
          id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.actions.RefactorActions"/>         

      <!-- Menu Shortcut Actions for Wizards -->
      <commonWizard
                type="new"
                wizardId="org.eclipse.ui.wizards.new.folder">
            <enablement>
                <or>
                    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile" />   
                    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder" />
                    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject" /> 
                    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot" />  
                </or>
             </enablement>
        </commonWizard>   
        <commonWizard
            type="new"
            wizardId="org.eclipse.ui.wizards.new.file">
            <enablement>
                <or>
                    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile" />   
                    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder" />
                    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject" /> 
                    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot" />  
                </or>
             </enablement>
        </commonWizard>              
  </navigatorContent>
```

Comment: Hello Greg, thanks a lot for your help! Does that mean it is declared in a class implementing `INavigatorContentService`? How come it is declared in an extension point *and* a plugin?

Comment: The use of an extension point must be in a plugin (in the plugin.xml) Context extensions don't implement INavigaorContextService - read the documentation on the extension point